# BroadcastReceiver not reading stored value from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences

In my app I have a broadcast receiver that turns on GPS upon receiving a set string of text. In the onLocationChanged method, I want to pass the GPS data and a value from my shared preferences to a thread in a string.
I have the thread writing to log and can see all the GPS values in the string but the last value from my shared preferences is just showing up as 'prefPhoneNum' which I initialised the string to at the beginning of the receiver class. I have the same code to read the prefPhoneNum from shared preferences in the main class and it works there, can anyone see what I might be doing wrong?

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements LocationListener
{
     LocationManager lm;
     LocationListener loc;
     public SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;    
     public static final String US = "usersettings";
     public String prefPhoneNum = "prefPhoneNum";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {    
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(US, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        prefPhoneNum = sharedpreferences.getString("prefPhoneNum" , "");
        lm = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        loc = new SmsReceiver();

        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();   
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = ""; 

        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];            
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString() + "\n";        
            } 

             Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     //Display SMS

            if ((msgs[0].getMessageBody().toString().equals("Enable")) ||
                    (msgs[0].getMessageBody().toString().equals("enable")))
            {             
                enableGPS();
            }    
            else {  /* Do Nothing*/ }
        }              
    }

    public void enableGPS() {  
      //new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {       //10 seconds
        new CountDownTimer(300000, 1000) {      //300 secs = 5 mins
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
            {
               lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, loc);  
            }
            public void onFinish() 
            {                   
               lm.removeUpdates(loc);       
            }
       }.start();          
    }    

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
      String s = "";
         s += location.getLatitude()  + "\n";
         s += location.getLongitude() + "\n";
         s += location.getAltitude()  + "\n";
         s += location.getAccuracy()  + "\n" + prefPhoneNum;

         Thread cThread = new Thread(new SocketsClient(s));
         cThread.start();
   }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {   }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)  {   }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {   }
}
```

Here is the logcat for when the application shuts -

```
D/LocationManager( 3912): requestLocationUpdates: provider = gps, listener = accel.working.TrackGPS@4628bce0  
D/GpsLocationProvider(   96): setMinTime 0  
D/GpsLocationProvider(   96): startNavigating  
D/GpsLocationProvider(   96): TTFF: 3227  
D/AndroidRuntime( 3912): Shutting down VM  
W/dalvikvm( 3912): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912): java.lang.NullPointerException  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:146)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at accel.working.TrackGPS.onLocationChanged(TrackGPS.java:63)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:191)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:124)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:140)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)  
E/AndroidRuntime( 3912):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing WAY too much in our onReceieve(). From the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle :

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only
>   valid for the duration of the call to
>   onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your
>   code returns from this function, the
>   system considers the object to be
>   finished and no longer active.
>
> This has important repercussions to
>   what you can do in an
>   onReceive(Context, Intent)
>   implementation: anything that requires
>   asynchronous operation is not
>   available, because you will need to
>   return from the function to handle the
>   asynchronous operation, but at that
>   point the BroadcastReceiver is no
>   longer active and thus the system is
>   free to kill its process before the
>   asynchronous operation completes.
>
> In particular, you may not show a
>   dialog or bind to a service from
>   within a BroadcastReceiver. For the
>   former, you should instead use the
>   NotificationManager API. For the
>   latter, you can use
>   Context.startService() to send a
>   command to the service.

Comment: Ok I've changed it so that all the BroadcastReceiver does is create a service that does all the GPS stuff, thanks Falmarri. But my problem still remains that in the 'onLocationChanged' method the value for prefPhoneNum is the initialised value of 'prefPhoneNum'. Do you know how to read from sharedpreferences in that method, or access the gps data in enableGPS() to pass to the thread I created?

Comment: There are no errors in code, but if I call the line      sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(US, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);  in 'onLocationChanged()' then the application forces close

Comment: What's the stacktrace? Post your logcat

Comment: Sorry I didn't know you replied, I think the error is something to do with onLocationChanged not having a context but I'm not sure, here is my logcat, thanks -

Comment: The program compiles and runs ok, it's only once it enters onLocationChanged it gets a null pointer exception runtime error. I posted logcat above. Is there anything else you can think of I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use the context passed from a broadcast receiver for what you're trying to do. You need to rethink your design. You're doing way too much in your receiver. Don't do disk i/o, or register listeners, or anything like that. Just use the receiver to start a service or an activity.

Comment: The only thing I am doing in my receiver is creating a service. Then inside that service I call onLocationChanged()

Comment: Then you should post relevent code if the code in the question is old

Comment: Ok I will post a new question with the code I am currently using and close this one. Thanks